# Unable to install Cloudera CDH4 on Ubuntu 10.04 VM

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I want to configure Hadoop on my Windows 8 machine with Ubuntu10.04 through VMware. I am trying to install Cloudera CDH4 on the VM, but I am getting the error below:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cdh/dists/precise-cdh4/Release  Unable to find expected entry  contrib/binary-i386/Packages in Meta-index file (malformed Release file?)
```

I have followed the following steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/
export CLASS_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

#Hadoop Installation steps :
/usr/bin/wget http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh4/one-click-install/precise/amd64/cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb


Can you please help me on this?
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using precise (12.04) repository on a lucid (10.04) based system.

Use this link instead to install cdh repository for your lucid based VM:

```
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/one-click-install/lucid/amd64/cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb
```

Note: Be sure to remove the existing cdh repository before installing the new one.